# Посоветуйте коллайдер

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите какой выбрать коллайдер,чтобы установить его на skinned mesh render - чтобы объект не проходил через стены

Comment: капсул по костям раскидай, как в ragdoll, за глаза хватит)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ на каждую кость?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ теперь модель по горам "катается"

Comment: Катается или скатывается?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ ну идет,идет потом крутой склон и он начинает идти и по часовой стрелке прокручивается и катиться с горы

Comment: Rigidbody заморозь кручения по осям, центр масс сделай в ногах(root)